# The difference between $\{\mathbb{N}\}$ and $\mathbb{N}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

$\mathbb{N}$ stands for Natural numbers.
What does each mean and how are they different.

Thanks.

Comment: Where did you find this notation?

Comment: Usually, $\{N\}$ would denote a set containing the one element $N$, whilst $N$ is the element. If $N$ is a set, $\{N\}$ would be the set containing the one elment (set) $N$.

Comment: Doe's answer is a good one, but I think it we, the ones answering, might not know what the context of the question is.  N might mean the natural numbers and {N} might, therefore, mean the set containing the set of the natural numbers.  Or they both might mean in context something else.  So I want to ask in what context did these terms come up?  (I have to admit the concept {N} as the set containing the set of natural numbers doesn't arise that frequently.)

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that $N$ here refers to any given set and not specifically the set of Natural Numbers, $\mathbb{N}$,

1. $N$ refers to any given set. It is what you define it to be.
2. $\{ N \}$ is specifically the set containing $N$, *and only*, $N$. Because of this characterising property where $\{ N \}$ contains one and only one element, it is known as a *singleton*.

The difference becomes especially important when we are discussing the empty set. For example,

1. $\emptyset$ is the set containing no elements, i.e. it is empty.
2. $\{ \emptyset \}$ is the set containing the empty set. It is ***not*** empty, simply because it contains the empty set $\emptyset$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I failed to mention that N stands for Natural numbers.

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbb{N}$ is a set containing infinitely many elements.  Depending on convention, $0$ may or may not be an element of $\mathbb{N}$.  So either
$$\mathbb{N} = \{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, \dots \}$$
or
$$\mathbb{N} = \{ 1, 2, 3, 4, \dots \}$$

But $\{ \mathbb{N} \}$, in contrast, is a set containing *a single element*, namely $\mathbb{N}$.  So (for example) the number $5$ is an element of $\mathbb{N}$, but it is *not* an element of $\{ \mathbb{N} \}$.

Answer (score 0):

$\Bbb N$ has infinitely many elements. Its elements are $0$, $1$, $2$, etc.

$\{\Bbb N\}$ has only one element. Its element is $\Bbb N$.